# How to connect 3 bluetooth modules using STM32 and?

Tags: c, bluetooth, embedded, stm32, hc-05

i am using **STM32F407** and **3 HC-05** bluetooth module. I am trying to use 1 master and 2 slave at the same time. I can connect any slave to the master. I am trying to implement a simple alghoritm for 2 slaves. I change device address which master is connected at 10 seconds interval.And when I try to connect both of them at the same time, my master always stays in AT Mode. It doesn't never blink fast (when it bilnks fast, it indicates that it is not in AT mode and searching for a device). Also my slave sends data. What is the problem with master?
Here is [datasheet](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/HC-05%20Datasheet.pdf)

```
int main(void)
{
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART6_UART_Init();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET); //Reset HC-05
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);// set high to 'key' pin  to enter AT Mode
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//set low to reset pin
    HAL_Delay(3000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6,(uint8_t*)"AT+ROLE=1\r\n",sizeof("AT+ROLE=1\r\n")-1,100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6(uint8_t*)"AT+CMODE=0\r\n",sizeof("AT+CMODE=0\r\n")-1,100);
    HAL_Delay(1000);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//exit AT mode
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart6,UART_IT_RXNE); //enable usart interrupt
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  while (1)
  {
       /* FIRST SLAVE */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//i entered AT mode to change slave addres
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6(uint8_t*)"AT+BIND=98D3,31,F63543\r\n",sizeof("AT+BIND=98D3,31,F63543\r\n")-1,100); //address of slave
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//exit AT mode

     HAL_Delay(50000);//wait for data transmission

        /*SECOND SLAVE */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//i entered AT mode to change slave addres
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6(uint8_t*)"AT+BIND=98D3:31:F537A2\r\n",sizeof("AT+BIND=98D3:31:F537A2\r\n")-1,100); //address of slave
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//exit AT mode

     HAL_Delay(50000);//wait for data transmission
 }
}
```

slave configuration:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);// reset hc-05
delay_ms(1000);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_7,GPIO_PIN_SET);// set high to 'key' pin  to enter AT
delay_ms(1000);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_RESET);// entered AT mode 
delay_ms(3000);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t*)"AT+ROLE=0\r\n",sizeof("AT+ROLE=0\r\n")-1,100);
delay_ms(1000);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_RESET);//exit AT mode
```

Comment: forget about the delay

Comment: which delay(s)? 50 miliseconds?

Comment: any - blocking delay == bad code

Comment: okay i will change. but they are not the reason of the problem, are they?

Comment: "any - blocking delay == bad code"   not argued and caricatural statement == bad statement